# OnSuggestionClicked in FloatingSearchView not working in ari morty library

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview

I'm trying to implement Floating Search View from this library: [**Floating Search View**](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview) so everything working fine but when implementing this code

```
 floatingSearchView.setOnSearchListener(new FloatingSearchView.OnSearchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuggestionClicked(final SearchSuggestion searchSuggestion) {
                Log.d("ssssssss", "clicked");

                mLastQuery = searchSuggestion.getBody();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchAction(String query) {

            }
        });
```

it's not working please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 6 hours i found the answer my mistake was in xml design so i put floating search view first child in coordinator layout so i change it to the last child and it worked perfectly